# FileUpload and HttpClient upload items and parts

Tags: java, file-io, upload

I can see this code

```
DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
        // If file size exceeds, a FileUploadException will be thrown
        fu.setSizeMax(1000000);

        List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
          FileItem fi = (FileItem)itr.next();

          //Check if not form field so as to only handle the file inputs
          //else condition handles the submit button input
          if(!fi.isFormField()) {
            System.out.println("nNAME: "+fi.getName());
            System.out.println("SIZE: "+fi.getSize());
            //System.out.println(fi.getOutputStream().toString());
            File fNew= new File(application.getRealPath("/"), fi.getName());

            System.out.println(fNew.getAbsolutePath());
            fi.write(fNew);
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Field ="+fi.getFieldName());
          }
        }
```

And I am wondering what this code part:

```
List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();
```

...means for HttpClient? Should I upload file by parts or what does it mean? I want to upload video files with my desktop app but I am not sure how to organize the HttpClient.
Please help me to understand.

---

Client

```
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class PostFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/uploadtest");
    File file = new File("C:\\file.flv");

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "binary/octet-stream");
    mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);


    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
}
```

server

```
public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Content Type ="+request.getContentType());


    try {
      DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
      // If file size exceeds, a FileUploadException will be thrown
      fu.setSizeMax(1000000);

      List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
      Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();

      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem) itr.next();

        //Check if not form field so as to only handle the file inputs
        //else condition handles the submit button input
        if (!fi.isFormField()) {
          System.out.println("nNAME: " + fi.getName());
          System.out.println("SIZE: " + fi.getSize());
          //System.out.println(fi.getOutputStream().toString());
          File fNew = new File("D:\\uploaded.flv");

          System.out.println(fNew.getAbsolutePath());
          fi.write(fNew);
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Field =" + fi.getFieldName());
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }


  }
```

I want to upload files >=1Gb. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to upload your files by parts. In your form, you can have multiple input field of the type "file".

```
List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
```

The above code returns you the list of all the "file" input field in your request. So, if you have two file fields, you get two `FileItem` with its content. The next statement:

```
Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();
```

is used to get the iterator and iterate the list of FileItem you just extracted from your request. Remeber, each FileItem object is a file that you uploaded.

Comment: mm.. that was not a comment.. it was an answer. Did you get what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to upload video files (>=1Gb) with HttpClient and FileUpload but I cannot find a really useful code examples. desktop->servlet file upload. Is there a standart tutorial for this task?

Comment: I mentioned item and parts because I maybe missed them with chunks HttpUrlConnection code way :) But there is a max_chunk_size limit so I cannot send video files with sun's UrlConnection :( That's why I put my attention on HttpClient and FileUpload libs but I cannot find apache video upload code examples :(

Comment: well, you didn't mention anything about 1GB files in your question.. First, what is the issue that you are facing? do you get any error, time out?

Comment: Second, the fu.setSizeMax(1000000) should be something like 1024*1024*1024.. the will set 1GB as the max. If you need more than that you will have to change it

Comment: I use this client code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro (adapted for servlet)

and this server (Listing 9-5) http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

But no file get uploaded :( How should it be adapted? I'd like to see some tips

Comment: Since you are handling large files, why don't you try FTP?

Comment: I'd love to but I cannot do this ...http only :( Is it hopeless?

Comment: No, all goes OK but no files at D:\\ appears?

Comment: Ok... I want to demo the code here. Please watch it because I have less experience.