# How to upload .txt file to http server?

Tags: android

I want to upload a `.txt` file(only) from a device to my server.  How can I do this?
I also want to be able to download another `.txt` file from the server to a device.

Any ideas where to start?

Thanks..

Comment: Anything more specific? FTP might do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpClient` and `HttpPost` from the **[HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)** library available for java to post a file to your server via http.  You can use the [**MultipartEntity**](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) and/or [**FileEntity**](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) class for representing your file data.

see example **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro)**, or see multipart example below:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);     

// add file content and metadata
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(targetFile, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
mpEntity.addPart( "commentText", new StringBody(commentText, "text/plain",
                Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```