# translating curl command into java/android

Tags: java, android, curl, httprequest

Can someone help me figure out how to translate the following curl commands into Java syntax for use in an Android application?

The curl commands are:

curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.org.snia.cdmi.container" http://localhost:8080/user

curl -u username:password -T /home/user1/a.jpg -H "Content-Type:image" http://localhost:8080/user/a.jpg

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) in Android for performing HTTP posts.

- HttpClient code snippet (untested)

  ```
  public void postData(String url) {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

  try {
      // Set the headers (your -H options)
      httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      // Add your data
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      // Execute HTTP Post Request
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (Exception e) {
      // Exception handling
  }
  ```

  }
- Check the following link for the basic authentication part (your -u option)

http://dlinsin.blogspot.com/2009/08/http-basic-authentication-with-android.html

- Check the following answer for your file upload (your -T option)

[How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pro)

Comment: hi ddewaele, i use PUT instead of post to upload file. it is same just change HttpPut ? thanks