# How to send an image from android to servlet and then store it

Tags: java, android, image, servlets

I am trying to send a photo over http to my server. So i convert the image to bytes and then i send it across as a name value pair. Here is my code below for doing so. Now my trouble is the server side, how can i recreate and store the image from the string of bytes recieved

i also am using java servlets

Code on android

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pinnedV.getPhoto().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo",new String(b)));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);

    try {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
     try {  
         result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
     } catch (IOException e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Code on server

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String fromClientphoto= request.getParameter("photo");
byte[] b = fromClientphoto.getBytes();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\img.png");
     fos.write(b);
     fos.close(); 
}
```

This above code writes a file but it will not open as an image. also is this `byte[] b = fromClientphoto.getBytes();` the correct way to convert back to same bytes as on the android phone?  any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem?  You have code to do both operations.

Comment: @Haphazard basically the error is my bim object is null –

Comment: I don't know anything about `ToolkitImage` so I doubt I can be of any help.

Comment: @Haphazard  but am i sending the image in the correct manner, also if there is a different way could you help?

Comment: Can you confirm if any data makes it to the server?  Debug or print out the size of the `b` array.

Comment: @Haphazard  yes the fromClientphoto string is filled with data . i did a quick println of it

Comment: Did you try writing `fromClientphoto` to a file?  Or the byte array?

Comment: edit added above....tried writing straight to file, that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with the toolkit image, just write the contents out to a file..

can you post an image to the Servlet outside of android? setup a dummy page that does the same thing through a basic HTML Form, break down the problem into smaller and smaller pieces until you figure out whhich piece is causing the problem...

Comment: So the image is converted to bytes and then a string is made from them bytes on the android phone......then server side i call the above to convert from the string to bytes...and then i write it to a file

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a file (i.e. image) as a regular name-value parameter from your device and read it with `request.getParameter(name);`.

Instead:

- In the Android side, use a `MultipartEntity` (see [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr)). It is already part of httpclient.
- In the server side, you can find [apache-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) useful (or other library that can help you to read the multipart content you receive in your servlet)