# POST request succeeds in cURL but fails in Java

Tags: java, php, http, post, https

The following is a snippet for uploading files using PHP. I am an Android developer and I want to upload a file. Which means I have to send a POST request to a URL that contains this script.

What is the parameter name that I should use if I want to upload a file?

**PHP**

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "https://some.site/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

When I try cURL, the file is uploaded successfully but when I do it via Java, it fails.

**cURL**

```
curl -F file=@call_me_now_2.wav http://some.site/upload/
```

**Java Code**

```
    File f = new File("call_me_now_11.wav");

    HttpPost filePost = new HttpPost("https://some.site/upload/");
    FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity(f, "audio/wav");
    filePost.setEntity(fileEntity);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.execute(filePost, new BasicResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws HttpResponseException, IOException {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            int c = 0;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while((c = content.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());

            return builder.toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr). But nevertheless an explanation.

One cannot read a binary file as done (as text). That gives problems with line endings, nul characters, character encodings, and again making it binary.

One normally would get the InputStream, here `content`, and stream it out, without first reading all into memory.

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
Streams.copy(content, out, false);
```

Of course on posting a form with file upload, follow the mentioned answer.

Comment: What you have suggested is a different way to handle the response. Can you show me how to deal with the request?

Comment: Sorry rereading my answer I think it inadequate. The form input name should be `file`.

Comment: Worked out, that was exactly the one I was looking for. Thanks.