# Gradle is failing to resolve dependency group:org.apache.httpcomponents, module:httpmime

Tags: dependencies, gradle

I am writing java backend testcases to check different post/get action on the server.
I have to upload  file using http post method, I am using this link for reference:  [How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr).

I am specifying external dependency in gradle.build file
gradle build is failing to resolve external dependency httpmime.

gradle build
Execution failed for task ':test-fwk:generateClasspath'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':test-fwk:default'.
>   Could not find group:org.apache.httpcomponents, module:httpmime, version:4.1.3

I am using compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.1.3' in build.gradle file.
Other dependencies like org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient and httpcore are getting resolved successfully.

I have spent lot of time trying to find the solution. Please reply if anybody knows the issue.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Are you using mavenCentral as your repository ?

Answer (score 2):

This minimal build script works to reference the httpmime dependency, running with Gradle 1.2

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies{
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.1.3'
}
```