# How to save a POST request content as a file in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, http

I have a client application that makes a  `POST` request to `asp.net URL`( it is used to uplaod a file to `.NET`).

How to make asp.net page receives this request and save it as a file ?

@ Darin Dimitrov
I have tried your code, but I got `500 internal server error` how can I track it ?!

Comment: I think this is a valid question. If you're doing an IFRAME post to upload a file for IE<=9 that looks like AJAX, then you need to create an html form with a file in, and post to a .NET page. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. So the question then is, how does the ASPX page extract the file from the posted data. Which is what the question is asking.

Comment: I agree with @Sean... this IS a valid question... not sure why it was closed.

Comment: I've noticed that at times, questions are closed because they are not worded in the best English. Which is an absolutely stupid reason for which to close a question. If the content of the question is legitimate, should anything else matter?

Answer (score 23):

If the client uses `multipart/form-data` request encoding (which is the standard for uploading files) you could retrieve the uploaded file from the `Request.Files` collection. For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
}
```

or if you know the name used by the client you could directly access it:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file"];
```

If on the other hand the client doesn't use a standard encoding for the request you might need to read the file from the `Request.InputStream`.

Comment: Can you please shoe me a full example, I am not expert in .NET. I have done with android client , and want to make the server side component ?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you sir, does this works for it as client side ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr/1068132#1068132

Answer (score 4):

You can also save the entire request using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(filename,includeHeaders)
```

Assuming the data is not being uploaded as multipart/form-data

Comment: tnx, I use this code in Simple-Ajax-Uploader when uploading in mvc or webforms. https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader