# How to add MIME type to POST request Java?

Tags: java

There is the following code:

```
public static void uploadUserpick(File file) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {  
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(USERPICK_URL);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("upload", new FileBody(file));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
}
```

There is the following problem - back-end code restricts a MIME type of POST request, therefore I need to set MIME type of my image file (File file). How can I set it?

Comment: Which version of HttpClient?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `"Content-Type"` header to the `HttpPost` based on the format for your image. For example if your `file` is a **GIF** image then you should add the header in the following way:

```
httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader ("Content-Type", "image/gif"));
```

Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in another answer the `addHeader` method actually has a more straightforward overload than the one I mentioned originally.

```
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

[I found out how to do this here.](http://httpcomponents.10934.n7.nabble.com/Setting-Content-Type-on-a-HTTP-POST-td18286.html) Just do this:

```
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may replace

```
new FileBody(file)
```

by

```
new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
```

[See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr) and [blog post](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/file-upload-apache-httpclient-library/).

Answer (score 0):

In case of spring you can do it like this using `MediaType` class

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/xml/private/secure/store.html"}, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) 
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody 
public StoreDTO returnStoreXML(Model model, 
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id,
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {

}
```