# I have an incoming HttpServletRequest that contains a request part that I need to pass into a new httpUrlConnection

Tags: java, api, rest

Let me see if I can explain this.  The front-end provides me with a spreadsheet that I need to pass to my central server via an api call to do the processing.  I use the following code to pull out the spreadsheet and create my work book,

```
Part spreadsheet = request.getPart(SPREADSHEET);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(spreadsheet.getInputStream());
```

Where 'request' is an incoming HttpServletRequest object.  I know that it works and I can manipulate the spreadsheet, but I need to pass it along to my other server to do the processing and I can't figure out how to do that.  Here is what I have so far.

```
@Path("/uploadSpreadsheet")
@POST
public String uploadSpreadsheet(@Context final HttpServletRequest request,@Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws IOException, ServletException, InvalidFormatException, JSONException {
    return uploadUtil(request, "rest/memberService/uploadSpreadsheet");
}
```

Here is the util that I can't get right.

```
private String uploadUtil(HttpServletRequest request, String serviceUrl) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException, ServletException {
    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8084/centralservices/";
    String urlString = baseUrl.concat(serviceUrl);
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    String boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";       
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Key", "SOMEKEYHERE");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("clientAddress", request.getRemoteAddr());

    //I know this is wrong but I'm not sure what goes here:
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("file", request.getPart(SPREADSHEET));

    int responseCode;

    StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            resp.append(inputLine);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        httpCon.disconnect();
    }

    return resp.toString();
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  I mean all I really need to do is transfer the request identically(with all the formparts and everything) to a different url. Once it gets there I have no issue processing it.  Let me know if I am unclear on something.  I'm pretty new to this stuff.  We already have a rest utility that I've always used for everything else, but it doesn't work for this scenario so I need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Servlet-Api 3.0, then the below approach gives you on how to read the stream and write back the stream to the subsequent URL.

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html

From your code above , once you get the Part , convert the obtained file/workbook to bytebuffer and then write it to Output stream.

connection.getOutputStream().write(filebuff);

Because adding to request property will not help in this case.

Thanks 
Maruthi

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of stuff missing in the multipart request. See this link 
[Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection).

Also it's probably better to use some API to do this for you, probably easiest would be [apache httpclient](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1)

See the example usage in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php)

If you do need to use URLConnection for this then you can use this [multipart utility from codejava.net](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically)

I'm posting the code from there here for backup in case original link goes down.

**MultipartUtility**

```
package net.codejava.networking;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This utility class provides an abstraction layer for sending multipart HTTP
 * POST requests to a web server.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        /*Following line has no significance for the task this utility performs*/
        /*httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");*/
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     * @param name field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();    
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Test Program**

```
package net.codejava.networking;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This program demonstrates a usage of the MultipartUtility class.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class MultipartFileUploader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        File uploadFile1 = new File("e:/Test/PIC1.JPG");
        File uploadFile2 = new File("e:/Test/PIC2.JPG");
        String requestURL = "http://localhost:8080/FileUploadSpringMVC/uploadFile.do";

        try {
            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

            multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
            multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

            multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
            multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

            multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile1);
            multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile2);

            List<String> response = multipart.finish();

            System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

            for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me the significane of this line " conn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour"); "

Comment: There is none, probably the person who implemented this utility forgot to remove it after testing, I'm commenting it out in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I was too unfamiliar with some of the options presented so I just converted the spreadsheet into a json string and sent that over with my existing rest utility.